# Log out from Google account on Android 6.0.1

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, google, samsung-galaxy-a5

How can I log out from my Google account on Android 6.0.1 in my Galaxy A5?

I tried the following:

- Settings -> Accounts -> No such option anywhere...
- Settings -> Cloud and Accounts -> Accounts -> Google -> [three dots top right] -> Remove account -> [some warning] -> Remove account (to confirm) -> [hint saying "Account is needed by some apps. You can only remove it by resetting to factory defaults..."] -> [back to square one]

Which defeats the point because then I'd need to re-install my apps, for which I'd need to re-login.

I'm happy to take unusual routes, i.e., brute force log out by deleting files, tokens or even the entire Android tree in the file system etc. if that's an option.

---

Fun fact: I managed to log out (I'm pretty sure it was via the second option from above) last time I logged in, which was about 2 months ago. Has something changed recently? Did Google become even more adamant in pressing down its surveill^Wservices down its users throats?

Comment: AFAIK it's been the same since last year (re: Option 2). It may make more sense to back up to Google cloud ( not optimal- at least most apps would be there on restore but yes you have to log in). Else, root the device, take a nandroid image, remove account and then after setting up restore /data

Comment: Seems to be some samsungian specifics. I had no problem deleting an account on 6.0.1 on other vendor (Settings -> Accounts -> Google -> three dots -> Remove account -> confirm). Tested it right now - there was no warning about resetting to factory defaults.

Answer (score 2):

Partly answering my own questions:

It appears that you can sign out any (other) device by going to Google's [recently used devices list](https://myaccount.google.com/device-activity?pli=1) and revoking the device's access. At the very minimum, the Play Store app will whinge with a permanent notification (one of the kind that won't go away, no matter how many times you acknowledge it) that you need to sign in again.

Edit: The notification goes away if turn off notifications for Play Store and turn them back on.

The downside:

Under syncing of app data etc. still happens under Settings -> Cloud and Accounts -> Accounts -> Google if triggered manually. Not sure how that's possible if the device has access revoked...

Man alive, this is an awful user experience... If Google was asking money for this kind of service, they'd be bankrupt tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this problem yesterday and solved it with some hints from Winston's own answer.

1. [Revoke phone access to Google](https://myaccount.google.com/device-activity?pli=1). After few minutes a permanent notification will appear on a phone. This notification is by Google Play services not Google Play Store.
2. Disable Google Play services in Settings -> Apps. There was a notification about Viber malfunction.
3. Remove Google account in Settings -> Cloud and accounts -> Accounts.
4. Enable Google Play services in Settings -> Apps.

Note: Samsung A3 2017, Android 7.0